# PhoneGap / Apache Cordova: Stuck on "device is ready" screen

Tags: cordova

I have a PhoneGap/Apache Cordova application, and I have inserted my own index.html page into the www folder, but when I run the application it doesn't go to the index.html page, instead it launches the splash screen which has the "device is ready" message. Where do I configure the launch page?

Index.html page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css" />
    <script src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" class="ui-bar ui-bar-b"> 
        <h1>Welcome to my app!</h1>
    </div>
    Username <input type="text" id="username" name="Username"></input><br>
    Password <input type="text" id="password" name="Password"></input>
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" class="ui-bar ui-bar-b"><h1>Placeholder</h1></div>
</body>
<style type="text/css">
body{
    border:0;
}
</style>
</html>
```

Comment: My guess is that it is not the splash screen that you are seeing. You might have included the `index.js` in your `index.html` file. You need to provide more details. Can you show us your `index.html` file. By default the cordova app picks the `index.html` file. The `index.html` file is picked up from the `platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml` cofiguration file(`<content src="index.html" />`).

Comment: there is no files in the config.xml... could I be missing files?

Comment: did you run `cordova prepare` or `cordova build` after adding your index file?

Comment: no, am I supposed to? I reverted to a much older version of PhoneGap and things worked for me, and for that older version I don't remember having to run a build or prepare command after adding a new file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're not editing the right index.html file. If you are building for android then there is a index.html file located in assets/www folder. This is the file you should be editing to create the first screen of your android app.

Note: The **www folder** will be hidden by default, to make it visible goto **Project -> Properties -> Resource -> Resource Filters** in Eclipse and remove the exclusion filters.

For more information check this: http://codezag.com/apache-cordova-android-stuck-device-ready-screen/

Comment: Any idea of the purpose of hiding this? I'm fairly certain the Apache Cordova documentation didn't explain this at any point!

Comment: Also, thanks for the answer, hopefully others will find this useful if they are stuck in the same position.

Answer (score 1):

The config.xml should contain an entry like `<content src="index.html" />`
Below is a sample config.xml file. The entry in the config.xml file can be overwritten by your own html filename, that will be used as the startup html file.

EDIT1: 
Oops. I completely forget to see your edited question.

You are missing an important entry in your **index.html** file.

You need to include the following in your **head** tag.

```
<head>
        <!-- Cordova Script Tag over here -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

        <!-- Jquery plugin over here -->

</head>
```

**** Sample config.xml below ****

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.company.appname" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTop" />
    <feature name="App">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Device">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
    </feature>
    <name>appname</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm building for iOS. An had similar problems. I'm a novice but have had a cordova app on the App Store for at least 3 years so I know this has changed. There is now a WWW folder and a Staging/WWW folder the later seems to be inportant. And two Config.xml files. Additionally, its important to drag an paste you HTML files/folders directly into Xcode which helps to build a proper index... They can be in the drive file structure but still not visible in Xcodes Tree/IDE thingy; which is to say they won't be grabbed when you build and run... I find the whole thing confusing but like I said I'm a novice.